# How iOS UI component controller works?

Tags: ios, ios5, uiviewcontroller, controller, custom-controls

This code works well:

```
UIDatePicker *pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[pickerView addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(pickerChanged:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

Why i don't need to add pickers controller to my UIViewControllers hierarchy?

```
[self addChildViewController:pickerView.controller];
```

I know, UIView has no **controller** property. But how UIPIcker component adds his controller to controllers hierarchy? Or UIPicker have no controller at all? Or this controller don't need to be in controllers hierarchy?

I need to know this to develop my own custom UI components, that should should be easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIDatePicker` is a subclass of `UIControl` that is a subclass of `UIView`
So its not a `UIViewController`, adding `UIView` to the views is adding using `addSubView`

If `UIDatePicker` was a subclass of `UIViewController` then indeed you would have to add it using `addChildViewController`

When you create your custom views its your coice, it will depend on what class you extend, if you extend `UIView` then you will need to use `addSubView`, if it will extend `UIViewController` then use `addChildViewController`